# Is there a python module that covers all html entities?

Tags: python, html-entities

https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

I tried the following. Neither of them can translate all the characters in the above link. Is there a python module that contains all the character mapping?

```
>>> from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
>>> h = HTMLParser()
>>> h.unescape('&Tab;')
'&Tab;'

>>> from w3lib.html import replace_entities
>>> replace_entities('&Tab;')
u''
```

Comment: What is the python version?

Comment: I tried python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the above URL with `beautifulsoup` with `html5lib` parser. Checking the output it seems it decodes all elements:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html5lib')

for ch in soup.select('td.named code'):
    print('{: <40} {}'.format(ch.text, BeautifulSoup(ch.text, 'html5lib').text))
```

Prints:

```
&Tab;                                    
&NewLine;                                
&excl;                                   !
&quot; &QUOT;                            " "
&num;                                    #
&dollar;                                 $
&percnt;                                 %
&amp; &AMP;                              & &
&apos;                                   '
&lpar;                                   (
&rpar;                                   )
&ast; &midast;                           * *
&plus;                                   +
&comma;                                  ,
&period;                                 .

... and so on.
```

Comment: OK. It sounds like this underlying table is complete. https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python/blob/master/html5lib/constants.py#L651